# C++ OpenCV: no instance of overloaded function cv::imshow matches the argument list

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a project with C++ OpenCV to show an image. This is supposed to be a basic task but I am having trouble with it. The imshow() function is not working in my programme. I am getting the following error message

`no instance of overloaded function cv::imshow matches the argument list aregument types are: (const char[14], cv::Mat)`

Can someone look out my code and help me out? I will really appreciate your help. My code is pasted below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string image_path;
    image_path = ("C:/Projects/NewWork/opencv/sources/samples/data/lena.jpg");

    cv::Mat image = imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    resize(image, image, {450, 450 }, 0, 0, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
    cv::imshow("Photo of Lena", image);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: `cv::imshow(cv::String("Photo of Lena"), image);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That did not solve it. It is still giving me error of no instance of constructor. That is happening for the cv::String. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I do not know if the error is as a result of the VS tool.

Comment: which version of opencv are you using ? 
In the 4.7.0, the includes should be:
`#include <opencv2/core.hpp>`

`#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>`

`#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>`

Source: https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using OpenCV 4.7.0 which is the latest version on their website. I have just done as you said now with the right include paths. The error is still there.

Comment: can you check if `image` as an object is correct ?

Comment: Try using a debugger as I can't see any trouble that would give this kind of error. Crash, exception thrown ok but that ?

Comment: Also, you could try in python the same code.

Comment: I have checked to see that the image as an object is correct. I also tried copying it to a different location and the same error occurs for imshow(). But when I move my cursor over the imshow() function which is underlined in red, it shows the message "imshow +2 overloads". I have no idea what that means. Once again, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: This is just the debugger telling you that this function has two prototypes. You can find them in highgui.hpp.

Comment: I appreciate your effort so far. I have just used a debugger now, but it threw out so many errors. Some of then are these ones. ``` E1690 cannot open source file "ctype.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "errno.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "float.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "locale.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "stdio.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "string.h"
E1690 cannot open source file "time.h" ```

Comment: Can you install on your computer visual studio 2022 ? that should be a first step because those types of errors show that the debugger / IDE you are using is not well configured and that would mean another questions. So drifting from the original questions. those errors are telling your that the debugger can't find the header files.

Comment: @Toyo and others, this is just to say thank you to you all and let you know that all is now working fine with the original code. After several efforts over two months to solve the problem and with no solution, I decide to uninstall and re-install my version of Visual Studio 2022 today. That eventually solved the problem. The issues about debugger you mentioned were actually related to the SDK10 that was in my old VS 2022 installation. The new installation uses SDK11 and they fixed the issue in that version. Once again, thanks. All is well now.